# Display checkmark &#x2713 in tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, tcpdf

I'm using **TCPDFs writeHTML to convert some html-code into a pdf**. This works fine so far except that the checkmark `(&#x2713)` is converted into a questionmark instead of... well, a checkmark ;-) The PDF is created as **UTF-8,** but neither feeding the checkmark itself nor the **hex-representation resulted** in showing the correct checkmark. I tried to used the fonts **Helvetica and Times**, shipped with TCPDF, but both only display ?. Any idea how to get the checkmark into the PDF?

Comment: Try with the checkboxes unicode character: `U+2713`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I meant by "feeding the checkmark itself" - which unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: is there any answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

@Nuno answer was a huge help. For those wondering, the `writeHTML` equivalent (as asked by OP) is :

```
<span style="font-family:zapfdingbats;">3</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Old post but it may help others.
Use the font zapfdingbats and the number 3 or 4.

```
$pdf->SetFont('zapfdingbats', '', 14);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(80, 10, 10, 9, '3', $border=1, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
```

Check the last example
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_055/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
html_entity_decode('&#x2713;', ENT_XHTML,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Anyone able to get this method to work? More appealing than changing the font for every instance. I made an attempt a couple different ways, by calling this direct with the `MultiCell()` method, assigning to a variable etc... can't seem to figure it out.